# Save / restore searched values in DataTables

Tags: jquery, search, datatables

I am using data tables with multiple search boxes, and stateSave enabled. The table will indeed save the state, but when reloading the table, the search boxes do not save.

For example, I have 3 columns... Book Author, Book Title, and Book ISBN. I have a search box for each column for greater searching power. If I search for "Mark" in author, all results with the name Mark in the author appear, as expected. Refreshing the page, or doing any other action which will force the table to reload (such as adding a book), the saved search results appear, but the search box is blank. To get all the items to reappear, I need to go to the book author search box and press backspace.

So... how can I save the state of the searchByAuthor text box?

Or... how can I get the value that was searched for, and what column it was used on? If I can get that, I can repopulate the correct search box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, see [this forum post](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/95109/#Comment_95109) by the author of the plugin who says

> This is expected. The filtering inputs are not something DataTables has any knowledge of - you call the `column().search()` method from them, but that could be from anywhere), therefore it doesn't (and can't) have the ability to reinsert the values into the inputs.

However, he does also offer a solution, which is to use `state.loaded()` API call to get the value of the saved state, and from there you can obtain the values in the column search boxes. The way you would do that is as follows ([here's a link](https://datatables.net/reference/api/state.loaded()) to the `state.loaded()` documentation where this example is from):

```
$(document).on( 'init.dt', function ( e, settings ) {
    var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );
    var state = api.state.loaded();
    var searchText = state.columns[/*columnNumber*/].search;
} );
```

Then, from there, you can use `searchText` to repopulate the value in the field. For more information on what data you can obtain from the `state` variable, check out [this link](https://datatables.net/reference/api/state()) to the `state()` documentation.

Check out those links if anything is unclear, most of what I explained is obtained directly from them, and will be explained in greater detail.

Comment: I solved the problem by something similar to state.loaded() - just using localStorage directly and obtaining the search real-time. On any reload, I just recalled the localStorage and put the value back in the search box. I later found the state.loaded() function, but my work around was already implemented.I have tried your suggestion and it works. Thank you so much for answering!

Comment: The solution provided to you at https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36311/save-and-restore-the-state-of-all-search-boxes is basically a sloppy hack. It disregards the relevant API methods, and instead, prefers redundancy. You already have `"stateSave": true`, which stores the data you need as Chris H. already pointed out. Just goes to show, you shouldn't copy and paste solutions from the internet without without RTFM first...