# Unable to stateSave with custom regex implementation of the search() API

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I enabled regex filtering in the following manner since the default is `false` -

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        var table = $('#companies').DataTable({
            stateSave: true,
            stateDuration: 0, //force the use of Local Storage
            // other code for 'dom' & 'buttons' properties
        });

        table.search($(this).val(), true, true, true).draw();
    });
```

However, `stateSave`, which was previously working fine to restore the search parameter upon page refresh has stopped working. It still remembers to sort the columns which makes me think that it is not working for search since the regex filter is being implemented externally.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38445350/3906773) mentions the use of `state.loaded()` but a comment beneath it says that it is a sloppy hack and `stateSave` should be used instead. [Another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45589971/3906773) went unanswered.

So, how can I save the search parameter with a custom implementation of the `search()` API?

**EDIT** - [Obfuscated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anishsana/r7d21584/) with the JavaScript intact but all the JSP code removed.

Comment: You mean when the page reloads the filter boxes got blank? If possible add your jsfiddle

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal I've edited my question with a fiddle and yes, when the page reloads, the filter box goes blank. This was not the case until I added `table.search($(this).val(), true, true, true).draw();`.

Comment: Anish you have to use `state.loaded()`. As I see you've mentioned that someone comment out that it is sloppy hack but if you see the comment again you will come to know that he was not saying about the answer, in fact he was talking about a [thread in dataTable forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36311/save-and-restore-the-state-of-all-search-boxes). So you can use `state.loaded()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38445350/3906773) and [Prashant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4816207/prashant-pokhriyal)'s suggestion, I was able to use `state.loaded()` to save the search term and populate the search box upon reload, as shown below -

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        var table = $('#companies').DataTable({
            stateSave: true,
            stateDuration: 0, //force the use of Local Storage
            // other code for 'dom' & 'buttons' properties
        });
        if (searchText !== null && searchText !== "") {
            table.search(searchText.search, true, true, true).draw();
        } else {
            table.search($(this).val(), true, true, true).draw();
        }
    });

$(document).on('init.dt', function(e, settings) {
    var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
    var state = api.state.loaded();
    searchText = state.search;
});
```